Why is supabase not returning any data when I still have rows of data in my table on react native?
I am using expo router react native and I am implementing supabase as a database option in my app. I have a console.log of the data from the select function but everytime I run it I get [] logged and nothing else. My select function can't read the data in my tables on supabase (my tables do have rows of data in it) How do I fix this issue? Here is the code
const checkTransferForums = async () => {
    const {
      data: { user: User },
    } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

    const { data, error } = await supabase.from('user_forums').select('user_id');

    if (error) {
      console.log(' ~ checkTransferForums ~ error:', error);
      return;
    }
    console.log(data);

    if (data && User) {
      for (const row of data) {
        console.log("In for loop");
        if (row['user_id'] === User?.id) {
          router.replace('/(auth)/');
          console.log('Transferring to home');
        } else {
          router.replace('/forum/userForum');
          console.log('Transferring to the forums');
        }
      }
    }
  };

I tried restarting my project a few times and I've ran the code at different files in my project, but they all return the same thing. I am expecting to see some form of data being returned in the array.

Do you have RLS enabled?

Yes i do have RLS enabled

So what are your policies like and can the current loggedin user read all the data in the rows you are expectig? Are they somehow linked to their userid or can any logged in user read everything? I am not sure but I expect that you get an empty array back cause you dont have rights to read any of the data as the current user.

I have three policies which include, select, update and insert all on the same table. I have tried deleting the policy and making it again but it seems that nothing works.

Update: You were absolutely correct about your hypothesis that it could be the RLS, fixing the policies now

Great!
This policy worked for my profiles table but this is the case where users should ONLY see their own profile, not anyone else:
create policy "User can see their own profile only."
on profiles
for select using ( (select auth.uid()) = user_id );
So profiles table has a column user_id which had to match the uuid of the logged in user.

It appears to be a policy issue. One potential solution could be to adjust the policy to enable read access for all users on the "public"."food" table, like so:
ALTER POLICY "Enable read access for all users"
ON "public"."nameTable"
TO public
USING (
   true
);

This statement grants read access to all users by setting the condition to always evaluate to true. Make sure to adjust the policy name and table name as necessary in your environment.
